# Change ActionBarTab line between items

Tags: android, xml

I am working on Android project, what I can't change is line between Tab items. Now it's light white / gray, but I want to make it black. I've tried to change style ActionBar.Solid.A with background to black, but it didn't solve the problem. Before I ask question I've check several similar problems, but didn't find solution...

[image]

## Theme Style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme.A" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_A</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.A</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.A</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.A</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.A</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.A</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_A</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_A</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.A</item>
    <!--<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>-->
            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.A.Widget</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.A.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_A</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_A</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_A</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.A</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_A</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.A</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_A</item> 
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_A</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_white_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_A</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_A</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_A</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_A</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownSpinner.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_A</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_A</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.A.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.A</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.A</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_white_color</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar TitleTextStyle styles -->
<style name="Theme.A.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/main_white_color</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar SettingIcon style -->
<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
<item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_dots</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to change is the ActionBarTab divider color. You can do it like this:

Inside `ActionBarTabStyle.A` definition, add:

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/tab_divider</item>
```

The tab_divider drawable is an `XML` file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90" >

    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:dashWidth="3dp"
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

**Edit**: An alternative solution is simply changing your `Theme.A` theme directly, adding:

```
<item name="actionBarDivider">@android:color/black</item>
```

Note that the android: prefix is not being used.

Comment: Well I've tried but nothing changed. Line is still light grey.

Comment: @boski Are you using Theme.A in your Activity?

Comment: It's Xamarin project, but yes I am using (because I see all other changes from Styles). When I change 'ActionBarTabStyle.A' background to red color my bar is red.

Comment: Why do you have `<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">` ? Shouldn't it be `<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.A" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">` instead?

Comment: When I change TabView to TabBar my Tab icons moved to left, and divider didn't change.